# Can i format full project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to format a whole project containing different files (like .java , .js, .jsp files) at once in eclipse.

If any one know please tell me it will save my most time.

thanks in advance

Comment: Yes it is possible. Check out Java EE Development, you'll need a specific version of Eclipse.

Comment: Am using Eclipse Juno

Comment: You want this: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/keplersr1 or you can add plugins to your existing install to include the Java EE portions, but it's probably easier to do a fresh install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the project the `Source` -> `Format`

Comment: As already said, this does not effect Javascript files.
Also the Eclipse behaviour, that you must define the Javascript Facet in your project to enable "Save Actions"/"Source Formatting" seems very odd to me.